# Speed-up for finding an optimal partition line

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization

This coding question derived from this [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/268581/finding-the-optimal-straight-line-boundary).

Consider an n by n grid of integers. The task is to draw a straight line across the grid so that the part that includes the top left corner sums to the largest number possible.  Here is a picture of an optimal solution with score 45:

[image]

We include a square in the part that is to be summed if its middle is above or on the line. Above means in the part including the top left corner of the grid. (To make this definition clear, no line can start exactly in the top left corner of the grid.)

The task is to choose the line that maximizes the sum of the part that includes the top left square. The line must go straight from one side to another. The line can start or end anywhere on a side and not just at integer points.

The Python code given is:

```
import numpy as np
import fractions

def best_line(grid):
    n, m = grid.shape
    D = [(di, dj) for di in range(-(n - 1), n) for dj in range(-(n - 1), n)]
    def slope(d):
        di, dj = d
        if dj == 0:
            return float('inf') if di <= 0 else float('-inf'), -di
        else:
            return fractions.Fraction(di, dj), fractions.Fraction(-1, dj)
    D.sort(key=slope)
    D = np.array(D, dtype=np.int64)
    s_max = grid.sum()
    for grid in (grid, grid.T):
        left_sum = 0
        for j in range(grid.shape[1]):
            left_sum += grid[:,j].sum()
            for i in range(grid.shape[0]):
                p = np.array([i, j], dtype=np.int64)
                Q = p + D
                Q = Q[np.all((0 <= Q) & (Q < np.array(grid.shape)), axis=1)]
                s = left_sum 
                for q in Q:
                    if not np.any(q):
                        break
                    if q[1] <= j:
                        s -= grid[q[0],q[1]]
                    else:
                        s += grid[q[0],q[1]]
                    s_max = max(s_max, s)
    return s_max
```

This code is already slow for n=30.

Is there any way to speed it up in practice?

## Test cases

As the problem is quite complicated, I have given some example inputs and outputs.

The easiest test cases are when the input matrix is made of positive (or negative) integers only. In that case a line that makes the part to sum the whole matrix (or the empty matrix if all the integers are negative) wins.

Only slightly less simple is if there is a line that clearly separates the negative integers from the non negative integers in the matrix.

Here is a slightly more difficult example with an optimal line shown. The optimal value is 14.

[image]

The grid in machine readable form is:

```
[[ 3 -1 -2 -1]
 [ 0  1 -1  1]
 [ 1  1  3  0]
 [ 3  3 -1 -1]]
```

Here is an example with optimal value 0.

[image]

```
[[-3 -3  2 -3]
 [ 0 -2 -1  0]
 [ 1  0  2  0]
 [-1 -2  1 -1]]
```

This matrix has optimal score 31:

```
[[ 3  0  1  3 -1  1  1  3 -2 -1]
 [ 3 -1 -1  1  0 -1  2  1 -2  0]
 [ 2  2 -2  0  1 -3  0 -2  2  1]
 [ 0 -3 -3 -1 -1  3 -2  0  0  3]
 [ 2  2  3  2 -1  0  3  0 -3 -1]
 [ 1 -1  3  1 -3  3 -2  0 -3  0]
 [ 2 -2 -2 -3 -2  1 -2  0  0  3]
 [ 0  3  0  1  3 -1  2 -3  0 -2]
 [ 0 -2  2  2  2 -2  0  2  1  3]
 [-2 -2  0 -2 -2  2  0  2  3  3]]
```

In Python/numpy, an easy way to make more test matrices is:

```
import numpy as np
N = 30
square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(N, N))
```

## Timing

```
N = 30
np.random.seed(42)
big_square = randint(-3, 4, size=(N, N))
print(best_line(np.array(big_square)))
```

takes 1 minute 55 seconds and gives the output 57.

- Andrej Kesely's parallel code takes 1 min 5 seconds for n=250. This is a huge improvement.

Can it be made faster still?

Comment: You should get great speed-up without changing algorithm by using `numba` package. Best speed-up would be by changing algorithm, but that would require some out-of-the box thinking and (probably) quite a lot of thought.

Comment: @dankal444 A numba answer would be awesome.

Comment: since you know about numba package, why asking? ;) Best try yourself, when you get to some problem, search stackoverflow, there's a lot numba-related questions. Finally, if there are no such questions - ask

Comment: @dankal444 I don't really know numba. I was just being positive. I suspect that good speedups will involve spotting redundancies in what is being computed but I could be wrong.

Comment: Very interesting problem that I'll spend some time on. Feel free to ignore the question if you wish, but is there a certain application for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This answer provides a much faster solution than the one of @AndrejKesely. Is also makes use of Numba, but the final code is more optimized despite being also more complex.

---

### First simple implementation

The initial code is not efficient because it calls Numpy function in a loop. In such a case, Numpy functions are very expensive. **Numba and Cython** are the way to go to make the code significantly faster.

Still, operations on Nx2 arrays are not efficient, neither in Numpy nor in Numba. Moreover, generating temporary arrays (like `Q`) tends not to be optimal. The solution is typically to **compute the array `D` on the fly without generating a temporary array `Q`**.

Here is a naive relatively-fast implementation we can write based on this:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

# Naive implementation based on the initial code: see below
def generate_D(n):
    import fractions
    def slope(d):
        di, dj = d
        if dj == 0:
            return float('inf') if di <= 0 else float('-inf'), -di
        return fractions.Fraction(di, dj), fractions.Fraction(-1, dj)
    D = [(di, dj) for di in range(-(n - 1), n) for dj in range(-(n - 1), n)]
    D.sort(key=slope)
    return np.array(D, dtype=np.int64)

# Naive Numba implementation: see below
@nb.njit('(int64[:,::1], int64[:,::1], int64)')
def best_line_main_loop_seq(grid, D, s_max_so_far):
    n, m = grid.shape
    s_max = s_max_so_far
    left_sum = 0
    for j in range(m):
        left_sum += grid[:,j].sum()
        for i in range(n):
            s = left_sum
            for k in range(D.shape[0]):
                qi = D[k, 0] + i
                qj = D[k, 1] + j
                if 0 <= qi and qi < n and 0 <= qj and qj < m:
                    if qi == 0 and qj == 0:
                        break
                    val = grid[qi,qj]
                    s += -val if qj <= j else val
                    s_max = max(s_max, s)
    return s_max

# Main computing function
def best_line(grid):
    n, m = grid.shape
    D = generate_D(n)
    s_max = grid.sum()
    s_max = max(s_max, best_line_main_loop_par_unroll_transposed(grid.T.copy(), D, s_max))
    s_max = max(s_max, best_line_main_loop_par_unroll_transposed(grid, D, s_max))
    return s_max

# Benchmark
N = 30
np.random.seed(42)
big_square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(N, N))
grid = np.array(big_square).astype(np.int64)
assert best_line(grid) == 57
%time best_line(grid)
```

The performance of this *sequential* code is not far from the one of the  *parallel* implementation of @AndrejKesely (a bit slower on my machine, especially with a large `N`).

---

### Faster generation of the array `D`

The above code is limited by the slow sort in `generate_D(n)` due to the rather **inefficient `fractions` module**, especially for small `N` values. The code can be made faster by comparing fractions in Numba directly. However, Numba unfortunately do not support keywords for the `sort` function so this feature needs to be reimplemented. This is a bit cumbersome to do manually, but the speed up worth the effort. Here is the resulting implementation:

```py
@nb.njit('(UniTuple(int64,2), UniTuple(int64,2))')
def compare_fraction(a, b):
    a_top, a_bot = a
    b_top, b_bot = b
    if a_bot < 0:
        a_top = -a_top
        a_bot = -a_bot
    if b_bot < 0:
        b_top = -b_top
        b_bot = -b_bot
    fixed_a = a_top * b_bot
    fixed_b = b_top * a_bot
    if fixed_a < fixed_b:
        return -1
    if fixed_a == fixed_b:
        return 0
    return 1

@nb.njit('(int64[::1], int64[::1])')
def compare_slope(a, b):
    ai, aj = a
    bi, bj = b
    if aj == 0: # slope_a is special
        if ai <= 0: # slope_a = (INF,-ai)
            if bj == 0 and bi <= 0:
                if -ai < -bi: return -1
                elif -ai == -bi: return 0
                else: return 1
            else:
                return 1
        else: # slope_a = (-INF,-ai)
            if bj == 0 and bi > 0: # slope_b = (-INF,-bi)
                if -ai < -bi: return -1
                elif -ai == -bi: return 0
                else: return 1
            else:
                return -1
    else:
        if bj == 0: # slope_b is special
            if bi <= 0: # slope_b = (INF,-bi)
                return -1
            else: # slope_b = (-INF,-bi)
                return 1
        slope_a = ((ai,aj), (-1,aj))
        slope_b = ((bi,bj), (-1,bj))
        res = compare_fraction(slope_a[0], slope_b[0])
        if res == 0:
            return compare_fraction(slope_a[1], slope_b[1])
        return res

# Quite naive quick-sort, but simple one
@nb.njit('(int64[:,::1],)')
def sort_D(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return
    else:
        pivot = arr[0].copy()
        left = 1
        right = len(arr) - 1
        while True:
            while left <= right and compare_slope(arr[left], pivot) <= 0:
                left = left + 1
            while compare_slope(arr[right], pivot) >= 0 and right >= left:
                right = right - 1
            if right < left:
                break
            else:
                arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right].copy(), arr[left].copy()
        arr[0], arr[right] = arr[right].copy(), arr[0].copy()
        sort_D(arr[:right])
        sort_D(arr[right+1:])

@nb.njit('(int64,)')
def generate_D(n):
    D_list = [(di, dj) for di in range(-(n - 1), n) for dj in range(-(n - 1), n)]
    D_arr = np.array(D_list, dtype=np.int64)
    sort_D(D_arr)
    return D_arr
```

The above `generate_D` function is more than **10 times faster** on my machine.

---

### Faster main loop

The naive main loop code provided above can be improved.

First of all, it can be **parallelized** though the code does not scale well (certainly due to the work imbalance caused by the `break` in the loop). This can be done efficiently with `prange` on the *outer* loop (using `prange` on the inner loop is not optimal because the amount of work is small and creating/joining threads is expensive).

Moreover, the loop can be **unrolled** so to reduce the number of conditional checks, especially on `j`. While the performance improvement can be significant (e.g. 2 times faster), this resulting code is also clearly less readable/maintainable (actually pretty ugly). This this a trade-off to pay since the operation is too complex for the Numba JIT to do it (and more generally most compilers).

Finally, the array access can be made more **cache-friendly** by virtually transposing the array so to improve the **locality of memory accesses** (i.e. accessing many items of a same row in the target grid rather than accessing different rows). This optimization is especially useful for large `N` values (e.g. `>200`).

Here is the resulting optimized main code:

```py
@nb.njit('(int64[:,::1], int64[:,::1], int64)', parallel=True, cache=True)
def best_line_main_loop_par_unroll_transposed(grid, D, s_max_so_far):
    m, n = grid.shape
    s_max = s_max_so_far
    all_left_sum = np.empty(m, dtype=np.int64)
    left_sum = 0
    for j in range(m):
        left_sum += grid[j,:].sum()
        all_left_sum[j] = left_sum
    for j in nb.prange(m):
        left_sum = all_left_sum[j]
        for i in range(0, n//4*4, 4):
            i1 = i
            i2 = i + 1
            i3 = i + 2
            i4 = i + 3
            s1 = left_sum
            s2 = left_sum
            s3 = left_sum
            s4 = left_sum
            continue_loop_i1 = True
            continue_loop_i2 = True
            continue_loop_i3 = True
            continue_loop_i4 = True
            for k in range(D.shape[0]):
                qj = D[k, 1] + j
                if 0 <= qj and qj < m:
                    qi1 = D[k, 0] + i1
                    qi2 = D[k, 0] + i2
                    qi3 = D[k, 0] + i3
                    qi4 = D[k, 0] + i4
                    mult = np.int64(-1 if qj <= j else 1)
                    if qj != 0:
                        if continue_loop_i1 and 0 <= qi1 and qi1 < n:  s1 += mult * grid[qj,qi1]
                        if continue_loop_i2 and 0 <= qi2 and qi2 < n:  s2 += mult * grid[qj,qi2]
                        if continue_loop_i3 and 0 <= qi3 and qi3 < n:  s3 += mult * grid[qj,qi3]
                        if continue_loop_i4 and 0 <= qi4 and qi4 < n:  s4 += mult * grid[qj,qi4]
                        s_max = max(s_max, max(max(s1, s2), max(s3, s4)))
                    else:
                        if continue_loop_i1 and 0 <= qi1 and qi1 < n:
                            if qi1 == 0 and qj == 0:
                                continue_loop_i1 = False
                            else:
                                s1 += mult * grid[qj,qi1]
                                s_max = max(s_max, s1)
                        if continue_loop_i2 and 0 <= qi2 and qi2 < n:
                            if qi2 == 0 and qj == 0:
                                continue_loop_i2 = False
                            else:
                                s2 += mult * grid[qj,qi2]
                                s_max = max(s_max, s2)
                        if continue_loop_i3 and 0 <= qi3 and qi3 < n:
                            if qi3 == 0 and qj == 0:
                                continue_loop_i3 = False
                            else:
                                s3 += mult * grid[qj,qi3]
                                s_max = max(s_max, s3)
                        if continue_loop_i4 and 0 <= qi4 and qi4 < n:
                            if qi4 == 0 and qj == 0:
                                continue_loop_i4 = False
                            else:
                                s4 += mult * grid[qj,qi4]
                                s_max = max(s_max, s4)
                        if not continue_loop_i1 and not continue_loop_i2 and not continue_loop_i3 and not continue_loop_i4:
                            break
        for i in range(n//4*4, n):
            s = left_sum
            for k in range(D.shape[0]):
                qi = D[k, 0] + i
                qj = D[k, 1] + j
                mult = np.int64(-1 if qj <= j else 1)
                if 0 <= qi and qi < n and 0 <= qj and qj < m:
                    if qi == 0 and qj == 0:
                        break
                    s += mult * grid[qj,qi]
                    s_max = max(s_max, s)
    return s_max

def best_line(grid):
    n, m = grid.shape
    D = generate_D(n)
    s_max = grid.sum()
    s_max = max(s_max, best_line_main_loop_par_unroll_transposed(grid.T.copy(), D, s_max))
    s_max = max(s_max, best_line_main_loop_par_unroll_transposed(grid, D, s_max))
    return s_max
```

Note that Numba takes a significant time to compile this function, hence the `cache=True` flag to avoid recompiling it over and over.

---

### Performance results

Here are performance results on my machine (with a i5-9600KF CPU, CPython 3.8.1 on Windows, and Numba 0.58.1):

```
With N = 30:
    - Initial code:             6461 ms
    - AndrejKesely's code:        54 ms
    - This code:                   4 ms     <-----

With N = 300:
    - Initial code:            TOO LONG
    - AndrejKesely's code:        109 s
    - This code:                   12 s     <-----
```

Thus, this implementation is more than **1600 times faster** than the initial implementation, and also **9 times faster than the one of @AndrejKesely**. This is the fastest one by a large margin.

---

### Notes

The provided implementation can theoretically be optimized a bit further thanks to SIMD instructions. However, this is AFAIK not possible to easily do that with Numba. A native language need to be used to do that (e.g. C, C++, Rust). SIMD-friendly native languages (e.g. CUDA, ISPC) are certainly the way to go to do that quite easily. Indeed, doing that manually with native SIMD intrinsics or SIMD library is cumbersome and it will likely make the code completely unreadable. I expect this to be 2x-4x faster but certainly not much more. On CPU, this requires a hardware supporting fast SIMD masked-load instructions and blending/masking ones (e.g. quite-recent mainstream AMD/Intel x86-64 CPUs). On GPU, one need to care about maintaining SIMD lanes mainly active (not so simple since GPUs have very wide SIMD registers and warp divergence tends to increase due to the `break` and conditionals), not to mention memory accesses should be as contiguous as possible without bank conflits to get a fast implementation (this is probably far from being easy to do though here).

Comment: Wow. Just a quick check, can you get the line from your code for the 7 by 7 case I give in the comments?

Comment: This is: np.random.seed(40); square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(7, 7))

Comment: The result is 23, like the two other implementations so far.

Comment: What do you get for the optimal line?

Comment: I get the values [available here](https://pastebin.com/k24cdZM0) (in a CSV-like format) for the variables i, j, qi, and qj (i is i1, i2, etc. in the unrolled code) when `s` is 23 (the final optimal result). The values are exactly the same in the initial code. Note I removed the `parallel=True` flag to print that.

Comment: I may be confused but don't they all indicate a straight line along the 4th column? I just want to check by hand that that actually adds up to 23 and the first four columns don't add up to 23. –

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand how the initial algorithm work. `(i,j)` seems to be the origin of the line and `(qi,qj)` the relative direction. This can be checked on a simple example `np.random.seed(40); square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(3,3))`. There is sometimes multiple solutions because there is multiple possible origine for a given direction. Theoretically, this replication of information can be used to optimize further the algorithm : one can remove the duplicates. However, this seems not simple to achieve in practice.

Comment: Note that the results for the 7x7 case are obtained on the transposed grid and not on the initial grid so you may need to also transpose the coordinates (this might be needed for the initial algorithm to be correct if you want to extract the coordinate of the line).

Comment: Yes, however there is no rectangle with sum 23 at all for this case.  Assuming the rectangle includes the top left square the maximum sum for any rectangle is 16. So there is either something wrong with our interpretation or the output.

Comment: Honestly, the result of the initial algorithm on the 3x3 seems already suspicious to me : the first 2 results are correct and optimal but the third seems wrong. Maybe we should only consider the first value reaching the maximum... Anyway, the behaviour of the optimized code should be the same than the initial one (at least, I always got the same results so far). Thus, if there is an issue, or something to understand, I think it is better to operate on the initial algorithm (which is simpler).

Comment: I found one giving 23 (it seems the optimal here -- confirming the max value provided by the algorithm). I am not sure how it matches the result provided above though. See the yellow area : https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5tBk.png .

Comment: That is a great confirmation. So it's just something wonky with the line that we seem to be getting.

Comment: Actually I think maybe q is the end point of the optimal line. The code just doesn't work for non-square inputs. How can your fast code be changed to report the optimal i, j and q ?

Comment: You mean the original code or the code of this answer? Admittedly, I did not test the code on non-squared input. Actually, it looks like the initial code assume the input is a square matrix before the computation (when building `D`).

Comment: I meant the code in your answer. I don't understand parallelisation well enough to see how you would output the optimal i, j and q.

Comment: The simplest solution is to print them. Unrolling does not make things like this simple despite producing a faster code. If this is fine to you you can just add a `print(i_k, j, qi_k, qj_k, s_k)` in the unrolled loop after each modification of `s_k`, where `_k` needs to be replaced by respectively 1, 2, 3 and 4. You also need to add a `print` in the `for i in range(n//4*4, n)` final loop. It might be better to modify the non-unrolled loop for such a thing (it is unfortunately clearly not meant to be modified/maintained).

Comment: If you want to store the output, then it is significantly more complex to do. Numba is not great for that. In general, in native language, we just add a critical section and append the result found to a global list in a critical section, but AFAIK Numba does not have any critical section nor any atomic operations (AFAIK it is not much better in Cython)... There are convoluted workaround for that. One of them is to store the result in temporary thread-local arrays and then merge the final array (cumbersome and not so straightforward due to other complications).

Comment: Honestly, If you want to store and check the output, the simplest thing to do is to disable the parallelism (just use `parallel=False`) and append the value to a list which can be then returned (printing is even simpler though).

Comment: I do need it to be fast. The only output I actually need is the line.

Comment: Can't the code be persuaded to return one set of variables per thread?

Comment: Yes. This is similar to the solution provided above (about the merging). You can manually partition the loop : 1 outer loop is `for slice in nb.prange(nb.get_num_threads())` and the inner loop is `for j in range(m*slice/nb.get_num_threads(), m*(slice+1)/nb.get_num_threads())`. The inner loop is not parallel so you can safely append items to a list in it. You can also put the inner loop in a function to make this a bit more clear. This solution might be less optimal than `prange` on some machine (because a static manual scheduling is less efficient than a dynamic scheduling here)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make a [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) version of the code above + make it run parallel with `numba.prange`:

```py
import fractions

import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange


@njit
def np_all_axis1(x):
    out = np.zeros(x.shape[0], dtype=np.bool_)
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            if not x[i, j]:
                break
        else:
            out[i] = True
    return out


def calculate_directions(grid):
    def slope(d):
        di, dj = d
        if dj == 0:
            return float("inf") if di <= 0 else float("-inf"), -di
        else:
            return fractions.Fraction(di, dj), fractions.Fraction(-1, dj)

    n = len(grid)
    D = [(di, dj) for di in range(-(n - 1), n) for dj in range(-(n - 1), n)]
    D.sort(key=slope)
    return np.array(D, dtype=np.int32)


@njit(parallel=True)
def best_line(grid, D):
    n, m = grid.shape
    gs = np.array(grid.shape)
    s_max = grid.sum()

    l = [grid, grid.T]

    for grid in l:
        left_sum = 0
        for j in range(grid.shape[1]):
            left_sum += grid[:, j].sum()
            for i in prange(grid.shape[0]):
                p = np.array([i, j], dtype=np.int32)
                Q = p + D

                Q = Q[np_all_axis1((0 <= Q) & (Q < gs))]
                s = left_sum
                for q in Q:
                    if q[0] == 0 and q[1] == 0:
                        break
                    if q[1] <= j:
                        s -= grid[q[0], q[1]]
                    else:
                        s += grid[q[0], q[1]]
                    s_max = max(s_max, s)
    return s_max


grid = [[3, -1, -2, -1], [0, 1, -1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 0], [3, 3, -1, -1]]
out = best_line(np.array(grid), calculate_directions(grid))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
14
```

---

Quick benchmark on my AMD 5700X:

```py
from timeit import timeit

N = 30
np.random.seed(42)
big_square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(N, N))

assert best_line(np.array(big_square), calculate_directions(big_square)) == 57

t1 = timeit(
    "best_line(np.array(big_square), calculate_directions(big_square))",
    setup="N = 30;np.random.seed(42);big_square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(N, N))",
    number=1,
    globals=globals(),
)
print(t1)
```

Prints:

```
0.023645485984161496
```

---

With `N = 250` the result is 22.5 seconds.

Comment: This is very impressive. Do you think this is as fast as it gets?

Comment: @Simd Calculating fractions with N=250 is costing ~1.5 seconds from the 52.5 seconds total.

Comment: @Simd With O(n^4) I fear it's hard to optimize. How big `N` do you need? Probably throwing more cores at the problem helps here (apart from microoptimizations)...

Comment: 500-1000 would be great if it were possible.I'll try more cores.

Comment: How can you get the optimal line from your code?  Apologies if it should be obvious.

Comment: @Simd When you checking `s_max = max(s_max, s)`, if `s` is bigger than `s_max` save currect direction and `i` and `j`. Then return them at the end of function with `s_max`

Comment: Did you mean  `if s > s_max: saved_i = i; saved_j = j; saved_q = q; s_max = s`  ? numba doesn't like doing that in parallel.

Comment: @Simd Yes, then you should derive the line from these variables.

Comment: @Simd I've added some micro-optimizations, used `int32` instead `int64`. I was able to compute for `N = 350` in 117 seconds (on AMD 5700X)

Comment: I tested  np.random.seed(40); square = np.random.randint(-3, 4, size=(7, 7)). This gives best_i = 3, best_j = 2, best_q = (3, 1). I thought this would mean a straight line through (3, 2) and (3,1) but that is the first four rows of the matrix which doesn't sum to 23. How should I interpret it?

Comment: The code I originally posted gives a different output with the same score for this 7 by 7 test case. It gives  best_i = 6, best_j = 6, best_q = (3,1) which makes more sense.